# Pass $scope along with $location.Path() in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two screens in my project, MemberList.HTML and EditMember.html.
MemberList.HTML displays all members with Edit link for each member.
When I click on Edit link, it calls the function ng-click="EditMember(member)" and code for EditMember(member) is

```
$scope.EditMember = function (member) {
    var getData1 = angularService.GetMember(member.ID);
    getData1.then(function (mem) {
        $scope.Member = mem.data;
        alert($scope.Member.FirstName);
        $location.path('/members/editmember');
    }, function (error)
        {
            alert('Error in getting Member record');
        }
    );
};
```

code for EditMember.Html

```
<div>
    <div class="bottom-margin">
        <div class="left-label">ID</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtID" id="txtID" ng-model="Member.ID"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-margin">
        <div class="left-label">First Name</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtFirstName" ng-model="Member.FirstName"/></div>
    </div>
</div>        
<div>
    <div class="bottom-margin">
        <div class="left-label"><input type="button" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" /></div>
        <div><input type="button" name="btnSave" value="Save" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Route configuration is

```
 $routeProvider.when('/members/editmember',
        {
            templateUrl: '/Template/EditMember.html',
            controller: 'myCntrl'
        });
```

Now the problem is, in alert it is showing me the First Name but it is not displaying any data in EditMember.Html.

Everything is in same angular CONTROLLER, there is no different controller is used here.

How do I pass $scope with member data to EditMember.Html? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use another controller call the service there on initalization of the controller

Comment: I think, when you call `$location.path()`, your controller is reloaded. Try to add `reloadOnSearch: false` to your route configuration. But in my opinion it makes no sense to change the location path if you work on the same controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike services, controllers are not singletons in angular.  When you changed the location, a new instance of that controller was created, and therefore a new scope.

Personally, I would pass a reference in the URL to the member you want to edit, e.g. `/members/edit/1234`, and load that data in when the controller loads, or during routing using [$routerProvider resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

Personally, I would also consider using a different controller for editing vs viewing, and moving any shared functionality into services - just to keep things coherent.

Answer (score 1):

@glennanthonyb, I did something like this....I am using the same controller here.

In route, I have added

```
$routeProvider.when('/members/editmember/:ID',
        {
            templateUrl: '/Template/EditMember.html',
            controller: 'myCntrl'
        });
```

and in the Controller I have added $routeParams parameter

```
if ($routeParams.ID != null) {
        GetMember();
    }
    function GetMember() {
        var getData = angularService.GetMember($routeParams.ID);
        getData.then(function (mem) {
            $scope.Member = mem.data;
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Error in getting records');
        });
    }
```

In MemberList.Html instead of calling a function, I am using href

```
 <a href="/members/editmember/{{member.ID}}">Edit</a>
```

I am not sure if it is the right way to do it or not but it is working.

Comment: Yes, something like this is good.  You may experience a flicker of mustaches before the data has loaded, but you may have already handled this in the template using `ng-if` or `ng-show`.  It's worth taking a look into $routeProvider resolve as a means to acquire data before the view loads, but use of this technique is down to the particular use case.